# Windows 7, office 13

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have successfully written macro for excel for indexing number in a cell for printing invoice/work orders. Problem is it doesn't remember where it stops and always starts back at 1. How do I slolve this? I need it to remember last number whenever I open the file
Thanks

Comment: Store the last number in a cell somewhere and reference that the next time you run the macro.

Comment: Please use question titles that say something about what the question is about.  Details about your platform belong in the body and the tags.